# Hand Tracing Loops

Tags: java, loops

Hello I was wondering if this loop with be an infinite loop?

```
for int q = 10; q != 20; q += 3)
{
System.out.print ( q + " ")
}
```

The reason I think this would be an infinite loop is because if you continue to loop it was always be opposite of 20 so yeah.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: (a) it won't compile (b) why dont you check if it's the case by running it?

Comment: Thank for your help @assylias but the thing is I don't have an ied at home and also this is for a test that I am studying for and our teacher wants hand written code therefore I am asking. Thanks

Comment: First try it before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop for ever because the sequence for `q` will be `10,13,16,19,22,...`. We've passed `20` without hitting it.

It depends on the type of `q` whether it comes back round to `20` after it overflows.

Comment: "It depends on the type of q whether it comes back round to 20 after it overflows.". In other words, it's not quite an endless loop. (even for a floating number type, the loop will end eventually - be it only because of the heat death of the universe or hdd crash - whichever comes first :P)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not an infinite loop. Lets change the loop's variable's type to `byte`, so it ranges between -128 and 127. Your counter will get the values 10, 13, 16, 19, 22 and finally it will be 127. After that, adding 3 will cause an overflow, and it get the value of -126, and than counting up again - -123, -120... eventually it will be equal to 20. If you are using `int`, same thing happens - it will take a little bit more time.

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain to me what an overflow is?

Comment: Overflow - trying to store a value that is bigger then the maximum. `byte` can stroe values of up to 127, so if you're trying to add 3 to it, you'll get 130, which exceeds the limit.

Comment: Oh okay so then it would overflow to negative numbers eventually landing again at 20 that makes alot of sense thanks and have a great day.

Comment: Yes. Try it by yourself :)